# How do i make 2 lines of text alligned with image in li

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

How can I make an image be aligned with 2 lines of text in a `li` elements?

I have posted a [sketch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zl4uA.png) to show more info about the problem.

[image: sketch for the list]

Comment: please provide your code.

Comment: It is expected that you at least attempt to code this for yourself. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. I would suggest that you do some additional research, either via Google or by searching SO, make an attempt and. if you still have trouble, come back with **your code** and explain what you have tried and why it did not work.

Comment: I have posted the sketch , sir. I do not know how to allign the text as I have shown in the sketch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `display:inline-block;` and `vertical-align:middle` on theboth  `ul` and the `img` tags.

```css
img {
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
}

img, ul {
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```

```html
<img src="" />
<ul>
  <li>Item 1</li>  
  <li>Item 2</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: My pleasure.. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
li:nth-child(2n){
   display: inline;
}
```